# Using VariationalD, getting derivative of Implicit Functions, derivative independent variables

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, variational-calculus

Hey I am trying to solve this problem with wolfram:

[image]

I figured using VariationalD was the way. However I can not figure out how this package works. It would be nice if someone could help me. I searched web but can not find any results.

Final code I am trying:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Needs["VariationalMethods`"];
u := x^2 + x y - y^2
v := 2 x y + y^2
F[x_, y_] := VariationalD[{u; v}, {u[x, y], v[x, y]}, {x, y}]
F[2, -1]
```

[Package for VariationalD](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/VariationalMethods/tutorial/VariationalMethods.html)

Comment: You don't need `VariationalD`, you need the inverse of the Jacobian matrix I think:  `Inverse[D[{u, v}, {{x, y}}]] /. {x -> 2, y -> -1}`

Answer (score 2):

```
u[x_,y_]= x^2 + x y - y^2

v[x_,y_]:= 2 x y + y^2
```

Now, δx/δu|v = (δu/δx)^(-1)|v. Therefore, we first calculate (δu/δx)|v. For v constant we have:

dv|v== δv/δx dx + δv/δy dy == 0

From this, dy|v:

dy|v== -(δv/δy)^(-1) δv/δx dx

with this in du|v:

du|v== δu/δx dx -δu/δy (δv/δy)^(-1) δv/δx dx

and therefore:

(δu/δx)|v== δu/δx -δu/δy (δv/δy)^(-1) δv/δx

δx/δu|v == (δu/δx)^(-1)|v == (δu/δx -δu/δy (δv/δy)^(-1) δv/δx )^(-1)

in MMA language:

```
tmp= 1/(D[u[x,y],x]-D[u[x,y],y]/ D[v[x,y],y] D[v[x,y],x]) // Simplify
tmp /. {x -> 2, y -> -1}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
(*1/7*)
```

The second question goes similar and I leave it to you.